# How can I check for uniqueness in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a dropdown-menu.

[image]

---

**JS**

```
$.each(responseData.assignments, function(i, v) {

    var assessmentId = v.assessmentId;
    var assessmentType = v.assessmentType;

    // Auto Populate the dropdown-menu
    $('#student-dd').append('<option value="' + assessmentId + '">' + assessmentType + '</option>');

});
```

---

**Goal**
I want to show only one HOMEWORK/COURSE_BENCHMARK, doesn't matter how many of them are there. How can I check for uniqueness in Javascript ?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for length of option element with same text in that dropdown using filter function before appending new:

```
$.each(responseData.assignments, function(i, v) {

  var assessmentId = v.assessmentId;
  var assessmentType = v.assessmentType;

  // Auto Populate the dropdown-menu

  var optionwithsametext = $('#student-dd option').filter(function(){
      return $(this).text() == assessmentType ;
  })
  if(!optionwithsametext.length)
    $('#student-dd').append('<option value="' + assessmentId + '">' + assessmentType + '</option>');

 });
```

Comment: But won't the `value` always be different as it is an `ID`? You should instead look at the `assessmentType`, which is the `text`.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ: quite possible. modified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to do this. This is an another example;

```
var assignments = {};
$.each(responseData.assignments, function(i, v) {
    assignments[v.assessmentType] = v.assessmentId;
});

$.each(assignments, function(i, v) {
    // Auto Populate the dropdown-menu
    $('#student-dd').append('<option value="' + v + '">' + i + '</option>');
});
```